# Remove All Text After Certain Point

Tags: php, string

Hey, I'm just wondering how I could remove all the text if it encounters a certain string inside a string :

EX: 24 Season 1 Episode 3

I would like, that if it find the text Season that it removes it and everything after so it would just leave you with :

24

Thanks

Ah sorry I forgot to say I need this in PHP.

Comment: Ehm.. in which language?

Answer (score 9):

With PHP5.3. you can use

```
echo strstr('24 Season 1 Episode 3', 'Season', true); // outputs 24
```

See

- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

and the comments on that page to see workarounds for PHP < 5.3

Answer (score 1):

```
$string="24 Season 1 Episode 3";
$s = explode("Season",$string,2);
echo $s[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `String.replaceAll("Season.*", "");`

Answer (score 0):

1.If u need all the strings which occurs after certain word this will work

$str="24 Season 1 Episode 3";
echo strstr($str, 'Season');

2.If u need all the strings which occurs before certain word this will work

```
$str="24 Season 1 Episode 3";
$arr = explode("Season", $str, 2);
$first = $arr[0];
echo $first;
```