# Remove characters after specific character in string, then remove substring?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I feel kind of dumb posting this when this seems kind of simple and there are tons of questions on strings/characters/regex, but I couldn't find quite what I needed (except in another language: [Remove All Text After Certain Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176544/remove-all-text-after-certain-point)).

I've got the following code:

```
[Test]
    public void stringManipulation()
    {
        String filename = "testpage.aspx";
        String currentFullUrl = "http://localhost:2000/somefolder/myrep/test.aspx?q=qvalue";
        String fullUrlWithoutQueryString = currentFullUrl.Replace("?.*", "");
        String urlWithoutPageName = fullUrlWithoutQueryString.Remove(fullUrlWithoutQueryString.Length - filename.Length);

        String expected = "http://localhost:2000/somefolder/myrep/";
        String actual = urlWithoutPageName;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

I tried the solution in the question above (hoping the syntax would be the same!) but nope. I want to first remove the queryString which could be any variable length, then remove the page name, which again could be any length.

How can I get the remove the query string from the full URL such that this test passes?

Answer (score 337, accepted):

For string manipulation, if you just want to kill everything after the ?, you can do this

```
string input = "http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?whatever";
int index = input.IndexOf("?");
if (index >= 0)
   input = input.Substring(0, index);
```

Edit: If everything after the last slash, do something like

```
string input = "http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?whatever";
int index = input.LastIndexOf("/");
if (index >= 0)
    input = input.Substring(0, index); // or index + 1 to keep slash
```

Alternately, since you're working with a URL, you can do something with it like this code

```
System.Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/what/test.aspx?hello=1");
string fixedUri = uri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(uri.Query, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Or would it be the last `/` ?

Comment: Oh, yeah, re-read that. He can do LastIndexOf("/") in that case.

Comment: Lets says that my input string is always like `http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx` and I just want to fetch the last value (somepage.aspx or abc.xml) from it. Then what to do... ???

Comment: @gsvirdi, in that case, you may load that URL into `Uri uri`, and then access `uri.Segments`. That will return an array, and "somepage.aspx" will be the last item.

Comment: Its shorter single line equivalent is:
input = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("/")+1);

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I have a string like "1,2,3,4,5,6" and I want to check exact char like '1,' and want to remove it from string even "," also  How to do it?

Answer (score 151):

To remove everything before the first `/`

```
input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("/"));
```

To remove everything after the first `/`

```
input = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("/") + 1);
```

To remove everything before the last `/`

```
input = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("/"));
```

To remove everything after the last `/`

```
input = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

An even more simpler solution for removing characters after a specified char is to use the [String.Remove()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove) method as follows:

To remove everything after the first `/`

```
input = input.Remove(input.IndexOf("/") + 1);
```

To remove everything after the last `/`

```
input = input.Remove(input.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: Be aware that these will all throw an exception if the string doesn't contain a "/" at all. Obviously this won't be an issue if you're working with hard-coded strings as in the original question, but in most cases, you'll want to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another simple solution. The following code will return everything before the '|' character:

```
if (path.Contains('|'))
   path = path.Split('|')[0];
```

In fact, you could have as many separators as you want, but assuming you only have one separation character, here is how you would get everything after the '|':

```
if (path.Contains('|'))
   path = path.Split('|')[1];
```

(All I changed in the second piece of code was the index of the array.)

Answer (score 4):

The [Uri class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0) is generally your best bet for manipulating Urls.

Comment: An example of link would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything before a specific char, use below.

```
string1 = string1.Substring(string1.IndexOf('$') + 1);
```

What this does is, takes everything before the $ char and removes it. Now if you want to remove the items after a character, just change the +1 to a -1 and you are set!

But for a URL, I would use the built in .NET class to take of that.

Answer (score 1):

`Request.QueryString` helps you to get the `parameters` and values included within the `URL`

example

```
string http = "http://dave.com/customers.aspx?customername=dave"
string customername = Request.QueryString["customername"].ToString();
```

so the customername variable should be equal to dave

regards

Answer (score 0):

I second Hightechrider: there is a specialized Url class already built for you.

I must also point out, however, that the PHP's replaceAll uses regular expressions for search pattern, which you can do in .NET as well - look at the RegEx class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .NET's built in method to remove the `QueryString`.
i.e., **`Request.QueryString.Remove["whatever"];`**

> here *whatever* in the [ ] is name of the `querystring` which you want to
>   remove.

Try this...
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension method to remove query parameters (everything after the `?`) in a string

```cs
public static string RemoveQueryParameters(this string str)
    {
        int index = str.IndexOf("?");
        return index >= 0 ? str.Substring(0, index) : str;
    }
```