# Cut a text on a string when '.' is found in the text

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove characters after specific character in string, then remove substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660723/remove-characters-after-specific-character-in-string-then-remove-substring)

I have a string variabel that contains a text like this:

```
"Hello My name is B and I love soccer. I live in California."
```

I want to cut the text after the first '.' so the text displays

```
"Hello My name is B and I love soccer."
```

How can I do it in the simpliest way?

I tried:

```
Char Mychar = '.';

Stringvariabel.trimstart(Mychar);
```

But I guess it's wrong.

Comment: @Oliver: You can limit the length of the array (see answer).

Comment: Actually, that duplicate is not too great, because it also removes the dot.

Comment: That makes it completely different :) Then another question arises: *"How to append dot to a string in C#"*

Comment: Well, I couldnt find any questions like this one, and there is good answers on this questions which could help many people that are looking for an answer like this. But whatever downgrade it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the first sentence, then just grab a substring starting at the beginning and ending at the '.'.

```
Stringvariabel.Substring(0, Stringvariabel.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Char Mychar = '.';    
Stringvariabel = Stringvariabel.Split(Mychar).First() + Mychar.toString();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `string.Concat` doesn't work on strings and chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get the result:

```
string input = "Hello My name is B and I love soccer. I live in California. ";
string result = string.Format("{0}.", input.Split('.').First());
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `IndexOf` function will do work for you..

```
string input = "Hello My name is B and I love soccer. I live in California. ";
int i = input .IndexOf('.');
string result = s.Substring(0,i+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One convenient way is to use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) and ask for just the first part:

```
var firstPart = input.Split(new[] { '.' }, 1).First();
```

This is quite efficient because it won't continue processing the string after the first dot, but it will remove the dot (if it exists) and you will not be able to tell if there was a dot in the first place.

The other option is `string.IndexOf` and a conditional:

```
var index = input.IndexOf(".");
if (index != -1) {
    input = input.SubString(0, index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TrimStart` removes characters from the start of a string that are in the list you give it. It would only remove a `.` if it appears at the very start.

You can find the first `.` and take a substring up to that point:

```
stringVar.Substring(0, stringVar.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
stringVariable.Split('.')[0]
```

or

```
stringVariable.SubString(0, stringVariable.IndexOf(".") + 1)
```

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to take the substring up until the first occurrence of the character.

```
public string TrimAtFirstChar(string s, char c)
{
    int index = s.IndexOf(c);
    if(index == -1) //there is no '.' in the string
        return s;
    return s.Substring(0, index)
}
```

Alternately, to avoid worrying about the case where there is no '.', you could use `stringvariable.Split('.')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

```
var myString = "Hello My name is B and I love soccer. I live in California. ";
var firstPart = myString.Split('.')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var splitLine = yourString.Split('.');
if (splitLine != null && splitLine.Count > 0)
  return splitLine[0];
```

Comment: This will not work if there happens to be no "."

Answer (score 0):

```
variablename.Substring(0, variablename.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: you can simple add plus 1 for the index

Answer (score 0):

Without split, only using `Substring` and `IndexOf` (which is more efficient when the text is very large):

```
int index = text.IndexOf(".") + 1;
String result = text;
if(index > 0)
    result = text.Substring(0, index);
```

http://ideone.com/HL6GwN

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that String.Split() can have an impact, cause you create an array that contains all substrings delimited by the given separator, but you are only interested in the first occurence. So using IndexOf() and Substring() makes much more sense.

```
string input = "Hello My name is B and I love soccer. I live in California. ";
var index = input.IndexOf(".");

var result = index > 0
              ? input.Substring(0, index)
              : input;
```