# How do you delete text surrounding a string that you want?

Tags: c#, .net, string, filtering

I've looked online for this but not been able to find an answer unfortunately (sorry if there is something I have missed).

I have some code which filters out a specific string (which can change depending on what is read from the serial port). I want to be able to delete all of the characters which I am not using.

e.g. the string I want from the text below is "ThisIsTheStringIWant"

```
efefhokiehfdThisIsTheStringIWantcbunlokew
```

Now, I already have a function with some code which will identify this and print it to where I want. However, as the comms could be coming in from multiple ports at any frequency, before printing the string to where I want it, I need to have a piece of code which will recognise everything I don't want and delete it from my buffer.

e.g. Using the same random text above, I want to get rid of the two random strings at the ends (which are before and after "ThisIsTheStringIWant" in the middle).

```
efefhokiehfdThisIsTheStringIWantcbunlokew
```

I have tried using the highest voted answer from this question, however I can't find a way to delete the unwanted text before my wanted string. [Remove characters after specific character in string, then remove substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660723/remove-characters-after-specific-character-in-string-then-remove-substring)

If anyone can help, that would be great!

Thanks!

Edit:

Sorry, I should have probably made my question clearer.

Any possible number of characters could be before and/or after the actual string I want, and as the string I want is coming from a serial port it will be different every time depending on what comms are coming in from the serial port. On my application I have a cell in a DGV called "Extract" and by typing in the first bit of the comms I am expecting (in this case, the extract would be `This`). But that will be different depending on what I am doing.

Comment: Seems like you don't have to, you can just replace the string with the match, or is this part of a larger string?

Comment: do u need to delete the other chars in your original string? can u create a new list of strings for example to work with? or just overwrite the original string with the text you have found in your string?

Comment: Huh? _'Deleteing the text surrounding a string'_ leaves just that string. So: Nothing else to do but replacing the oldstring with the string you want..?

Answer (score 0):

Find the position of the string you want, delete from the beginning to the predecessor of that position, then delete everything from the length of your string to the end.

String: efefhokiehfdThisIsTheStringIWantcbunlokew

Step 1 - "ThisIsTheStringIWant" starts at position 13, so delete the first twelve, leaving...

String: ThisIsTheStringIWantcbunlokew

Step 2 - "ThisIsTheStringIWant" is 20 characters long, so delete from character  21 to the length of the string, leaving:

String: ThisIsTheStringIWant

Comment: Wait... if you already know the string you want, why are you deleting the text around it - I think we're missing something fundamental from the requirements...

Comment: In my form I have a cell called "Extract". Whatever is typed into this will find a match in the string. e.g. if I type "This" then it will find "ThisIsTheStringIWant" and add it to a dictionary. The problem I am having is that as so many comms will be coming in at the same time, they are going into a buffer so that the UI is not slowed down. After the incoming comms reach the buffer, I want to delete the text I do not need - i.e "efefhokiehfd" and "bunlokew". How do I delete the rest of the text?