# The use of Lastindexof and Remove in C# for database confusion

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, winforms

Ok iv tried everything i cant get this to work it shows me nothing:

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            keyNameTextBox.Text = dr["KeyName"].ToString().Remove(keyNameTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf("_") + 1); ;

            keyTextBox.Text = dr["Key"].ToString();

        }
```

if I change after .Remove (0
it then gives me the result which is good but only everything after _

But My goal is to see everything before _ excluding the _

Iv seen a Stack Overflow posts which helped me find out about indexof and remove but for some reason both not working for me is it because im in a for each ? how would i get around it ? any help would be awesome!

Source i used:
[Remove characters after specific character in string, then remove substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660723/remove-characters-after-specific-character-in-string-then-remove-substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
dr["KeyName"].ToString().Remove(keyNameTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf("_") + 1);
```

you search in one string (`keyNameTextBox.Text`) and remove from another (`dr["KeyName"].ToString()`).

What you really need is something like this:

```
var keyName = dr["KeyName"].ToString();
keyNameTextBox.Text = keyName.Remove(keyName.LastIndexOf("_") + 1);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks that worked like a charm, There is always going to be _ in the keyname because i made sure when the user adds the key then the keyname my code puts _ at the end with their username to make it unique so it doesnt come up as a duplicate in my DB.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove that part :)

Comment: instead of making another post what about for my combo box ? is it the same thing because i am trying : 

var keyName = dr["KeyName"].ToString(); keyComboBox.Text = keyName.Remove(keyName.LastIndexOf("_")); 

basically same thing as the solution above but nothing happens.

Comment: Sounds unrelated. Depends of what do you have inside the combobox list and if the control is configured to accept non existing items. Without seeing the actual control properties and content it's hard to tell why nothing happens.

Comment: foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
 //STILL NEED TO DO STRING MANIPULATION HERE! NOT WORKING ATM!
                keyComboBox.Items.Add(dr["KeyName"]).ToString();

                var keyName = dr["KeyName"].ToString();
                keyComboBox.Text = keyName.Remove(keyName.LastIndexOf("_"));
            }

User selects a keyname from combobox which works but with _and stuff after it, then the text box shows with the keyname which works now because of your solution (This is for users being able to update/delete their keys). Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Now you are adding one string and setting another:) It should be something like: `var keyName = dr["KeyName"].ToString(); keyName = keyName.Remove(keyName.LastIndexOf("_")); keyComboBox.Items.Add(keyName); keyComboBox.Text = keyName;`