# Substring a HTTP Response into a Variable [C# Winforms]

Tags: c#, winforms, http, substring, httpwebrequest

Im trying to get a cryptocurrency last price value from a HTTP API:

The following piece of code:

```
 // Create the web request  
 HttpWebRequest request = 
 WebRequest.Create("APISITE") as 
 HttpWebRequest;

        // Get response  
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            // Get the response stream  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            // Console application output  
            currentXRPPrice.Text = (reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Gives me the following response which is correct:

```
{"high": "1.15600", "last": "1.08269", "timestamp": "1518697359", "bid": "1.08034", "vwap": "1.09634", "volume": "40858340.75727354", "low": "1.03051", "ask": "1.08269", "open": "1.13489"}
```

What I want is just the value of "last" which is "1.08269". 
I have tried using this post: [link] ([Remove characters after specific character in string, then remove substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660723/remove-characters-after-specific-character-in-string-then-remove-substring))
 which has worked wonders for me on previous projects. But I cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

Iv tried below to get the value of "last" but its completely wrong, I have tried many of the different combinations to get it right but its not working to show me just the value for "Last".

```
        response = currentXRPPrice.Text;
        response = response.Remove(response.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        profitLossText.Text = response; //Still wrong tried 4 combinations none work.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't use string manipulation, create a Type that models the response and deserialize the json into your object with [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: The reponse format is "JSON". Look it up. For .Net I would use Newtonsoft

Comment: Cheers for the responses. Ill check Newstonsoft out right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Newtonsoft.Json from Nuget packages and use `Parse` method from `JObject`:

```
var lastValue = JObject.Parse(currentXRPPrice.Text).SelectToken("last").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have Json string, you can define a class which represent this object and then you just deserialize this string to object using generic method.

```
var jsonString = currentXRPPrice.Text;
var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReponseType>(jsonString);
var lastValue = deserializedResponse.Last;

public class ReponseType
{
    ...
    public float Last { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can do it by Regex too:

```
var lastValue = Regex.Match(jsonString, @"last\": \"(\\d+\\.\\d+)"").Groups[0];
```